# C2679 binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'point_t' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, vector, methods, iterator

Im trying to do a method which writes vector in .csv file and "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'point_t' (or there is no acceptable conversion)" keeps popping out, ive seen many similiar problems to this one but no solution can help me with this...

Method:

```
result_en CLogger::Log(const vector<point_t>& pointsVector)

vector<point_t> tmp;
tmp = pointsVector;

if (this->binary == false)
{
    std::copy(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), std::ostream_iterator<point_t>(file, ";"));

    return res_ok;
}
```

I've included vector,cstdlib,iterator,fstream nothing works.

Comment: So what is `point_t`?

Comment: Does `point_t` support copy assignment?

Comment: Ohh sorry i forgot to add this...struct point_t
{
    double x, y, z;
};

Comment: Sergey can you explane me what did you mean in supporting copy assignment ? maybe this is the problem

Comment: This won't work unless `point_t` has a supporting `std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&,point_t const&)` free function. If you don't have one of those, perhaps you should provide one?

Comment: @WojtekPtasinski as far as I understand the error message, this particular error informs you that `operator=` was not found for `point_t`. It's not the point though because `operator=` should have been generated for your `struct point_t`. The answer probably lies in other comments about `operator<<`

Answer (score 1):

You need declared function like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const point_t& p)
{
     return s << '(' << p.x << ',' << p.y << ',' << p.z << ')';
}
```